# Remove Span Tags From Woocommerce Price

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I Want to remove span Tags autour the price

```
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>15</span>
```

Comment: what have you tried? Which problems you had with your solution? [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the follows code snippet in your active theme's functions.php -

```
function modify_wc_price( $return, $price, $args ) {
    // remove span tags
    $negative          = $price < 0;
    $formatted_price = ( $negative ? '-' : '' ) . sprintf( $args['price_format'], get_woocommerce_currency_symbol( $args['currency'] ), $price );
    return $formatted_price;
}
add_filter( 'wc_price', 'modify_wc_price', 99, 3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code and change span tags with your tags, you want to use:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','woocommerce_template_single_price',10);
function woocommerce_template_single_price() {
    $price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', true);
    $price_sale = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_sale_price', true);
?>
    <del>
        <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
            <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span><?php echo $price; ?>.00
        </span>
    </del>
    <ins>
        <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
            <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span><?php echo $price_sale; ?>.00
        </span>
    </ins>
<?php }
```